# Error on init/boot '/init: line 27: can't create /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger'

Tags: boot, raspbian-jessie, config.txt, init, recovery

Sorry for asking the same question twice, but it seems I can't fix the problem yet. I have a web server running on my pi. One day I found that my server is down and I try to access my pi using VNC and I can't. I plugged in HDMI, keyboard and mouse and reset the pi. When it tries to boot I get the color test screen and after a few seconds this messages appears on the screen:

```
/init: line 27: can't create /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger: nonexistent directory
[    1.629060] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = w10: May 27 2016 00:13.30 version 7.45.41.26 (r640327) FWID 01-df77e4a7
[    1.656696] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg0021_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
```

After that the recovery screen pops up. I searched in config.txt but there was no "device_tree=". I tried to add it to the config.txt, and boot it that way but there was no difference. I also tried to change cmdline.txt to boot from partition 2 insted of 7: `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` instead of `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` but there was no result. And now I'm wondering what to do. I really need to make my pi to work. I had a web site running on it and all my files and configurations will be gone... Is there any way I can fix that problem or recover my system? I don't want to lose all my information, settings and files.

Comment: Your question is effectively - You are running UNKNOWN applications  on an UNKNOWN model Pi which developed boot problems. You problem is most likely a corrupted filesystem - most of us would just restore from backup. If you don't have a backup do a new installation, and if you are lucky you may be able to recover your files.

Comment: I tried to read all the files in the ext4 partitions using DiskInternals Linux reader and all my files was there. But i can' t access the /init file. It seems Diskinternals doesn't show all files in the partition. I'm net to raspberry and linux so excuse my lack of knowledge.